# Flair for Unicode usernames broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, flair

The "flair" link in the profiles for people with all-Unicode usernames is broken.

For example, clicking on it for [this guy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/11062) links to [this page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/11062//flair).

What's happening here is that the flair link is `http://site.stackexchange.com/users/<userid>/<username slug>/flair`. For such usernames, the slug is blank, which leads to `http://site.stackexchange.com/users/<userid>//flair`, which is just a link to the profile.

Could this be fixed? To fix it, we could either have the system recognize the double-slash, or remove the slug from the flair link (I don't see why it's needed).

Comment: Alternative: have a "default" slug that is used when a username would lead to an empty slug.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: something like `/flair/flair`? Yeah :). It may be a good idea to do this everywhere where Unicode rears its ugly head.

Comment: Yeah, although a sensible default might be something that can't actually be generated as a slug (but is still valid in a URL). Maybe `/./flair` or some such thing.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm rather confused as to why people are downvoting this... are they denying the existence of the bug? Or claiming that it shouldn't be fixed? Some explanatory comments would be useful.

Comment: Actually the issue is not with the flair only. The issue is that the username is not added in the URL when we click on the link of his profile. E.g. Click on his name from [his question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34491/23220). Now click on other user's name from [his question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47178/23220). You will see that the name is not added in the profile URL of Ϛѓăʑɏ βµԂԃϔ. So the same issue with the flair. (PS: If we don't add username in user profile URL, we can still load user profile but if we don't add username in flair link,we can't load it's flair page)

Comment: @hims056: That's a nice point..! So, these special *chars* in my name don't follow the profile ID unlike other users. Indeed, it can be seen in comments too. For instance, click on your name (in the comment above) and do the same to mine. Gotcha ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flair link is not working?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220238/flair-link-is-not-working)

Comment: Dupe-closing in the other direction since the newer report is now resolved and the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our slug routines were not handling the exotic characters in the display name at all and were stripping them out.

I have made a change in cases where all characters were stripped to use the user ID instead (yes, it will appear twice), so the link will get you to the page.

With you in the next build (Meta: rev 2014.2.10.1933, main rev 2014.2.10.1358).