# Flair link is not working?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, display-names, unicode

There seems to be an issue with the flair link. On any site, after going to the user profile page, if I click on the `flair` link, its is not taking me to the flair page. Instead it stays on the same page with the URL of the page changes to this

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/216721//flair

This seems to be a bug where an extra `/` is added to the URL.

*Update:* As [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140890/martijn-pieters) pointed out, it seems that because of the characters in my username, the URL is not getting generated properly. But I'd like to point out that, if such characters are allowed to be entered as a part of the username, then the system should handle them as well.

Comment: Is it something to do with having no ASCII characters in your username?

Comment: Interestingly, as Martijn has pointed out (and I have tried it also), made-up username-slug is accepted as long as it's not blank. I'd like to propose 1) using standard placeholder (e.g. `user`, becomes `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/216721/user/flair`), or 2) accept empty username-slug, removing double-slashes (`http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/216721/flair)

Comment: @AndrewT. FYI, accepting an empty username slug wouldn't work: `/users/216721/flair` would cause `flair` to be interpreted as the slug.

Comment: @michaelb958 Ah, you're correct, I forgot that anything after `user id` is interpreted as `user slug`.

Comment: @AndrewT.: Since this report has now been marked as completed and Oded posted a 'fixed' answer with explanation here, I voted to close as dupe in the other direction instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our slug routines were not handling the exotic characters in your name at all and were stripping them out. With only a single `.` being used, it also gets stripped out, causing an empty slug to be used.

I have made a change in such cases to use the user ID instead (yes, it will appear twice), so the link will get you to the page that is usable.

With you in the next build (Meta: rev 2014.2.10.1933, main rev 2014.2.10.1358).

Comment: You may want to mark the [older report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180617/flair-for-unicode-usernames-broken) as completed as well then, or mark that one a dupe of this one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - thanks for pointing me to that one.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by your username. This works:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/216721/r-j/flair

The URL path for your normal profile uses your username, converted to an ASCII-slug, but your use of characters outside of the ASCII range confuses the slug-generator and your profile has no such slug; this is your profile URL:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/216721/

The flair path simply tacks on `/flair` to your profile URL but this does require there to be **something** in the `username-slug` section of the URL path. The slug is not actually validated, so making one up makes the URL work. I jused `r-j` but you could use `thisisabug` as well.

The bug then is that the link in your profile is not correctly generated and / or that your profile URL has no username slug at all.

Comment: Even then, shouldn't it be a bug? If you're allowed to have weird ASCII characters in the username, then this should have been handled too right?

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ: I wasn't finished yet! :-P Yes it is a bug.

Comment: I've a small request. I did not understand the second half of your answer, but I did understand that this seems to be a bug. Can you please, on my behalf edit my question to reflect the actual issue?

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ: You got it in one already. My name is 'sluggified' to `martijn-pieters`; it's the name reduced to something that is URL-safe and easily readable. So my profile URL is `http://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters`, note the name in the URL, and the flair link is `http://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters/flair`.